# Gitlab CI - caching Node.js dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, gitlab-ci, npm-ci

I'm having significant problems trying to reuse the packages installed with `npm ci` between jobs. I have been following this documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/#cache-nodejs-dependencies, but the packages are reinstalled each step anyway:

```
$ npm ci --cache node_modules --prefer-offline
added 1895 packages, and audited 1896 packages in 41s
```

Here's my yaml. The files are within a folder called `frontend`.

```
stages:
  - lint
  - test
  - build
  
image: node:15-alpine

# Cache modules in between jobs
cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  paths:
    - frontend/.npm/

before_script:
  - cd frontend
  - npm ci --cache .npm --prefer-offline

do-lint:
  stage: lint
  script:
    - ./node_modules/.bin/eslint src
    - ./node_modules/.bin/stylelint "src/*.{css,scss}"

test-front-end:
  stage: test
  script:
    # Force tests to run in CI mode
    - CI=true npm test
  coverage: '/^All\sfiles.*?\s+\d+.\d+.*?\s+(\d+.\d+)/'

do-build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm run build
```

Would very much appreciate some assistance!

Comment: Give the path of **node_modules** under `paths` in cache module.

Comment: Thanks @SouravAtta. I ended up creating a new stage to do the installs, and then using artefacts to pass the files between jobs. Got there eventually :-)